# MS Word 2007: the document map pane shows about everything after a remote edit. How to revert to titles only?

Tags: microsoft-word

In MS Word 2007 I have following settings: `View > Page Layout` and `Document Map` is activated.

This provides a view of the document structure, i.e., I see all titles in the left pane and can jump quickly to them.

Yesterday, I edited this 200 pages document on a remote PC having a different version (Word 2013).

On re-opening my document this morning on the standard machine, I find that the left pane now lists practically every sentence, figure etc.

I did a quite exhaustive search within Word but could not find a setting to revert to display titles only. Where can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Miscrosoft answer did the trick for me:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other-mso_2007/document-map-figures/05192faa-6e72-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5

Quote from the answerer:

"To determine the  paragraph outline level, put the cursor in one of your caption paragraphs that have been caught  in the document map.  On the Home ribbon, click the Paragraph group's launcher arrow (lower right).  The outline level will say "Level 1", or some such.  Change the level to "Body Text" and that caption will disappear from the document map.

Because Word changes the  outline levels with direct formatting, you can select a caption paragraph (or all of them at once)  and press Ctrl+q to clear the direct paragraph formatting. -- Pam"